# Using Separate Serif and SansSerif Fonts in a Document

Tags: pgfplots, sans-serif

I have a bunch of figures that I am compiling using the `standalone` class in which I load two font packages `mathpazo` for the serif fonts and `cabin` for the sans serif fonts. The problem is that when I load in the `cabin` package, neither font gets used in the output pdf, everything reverts to the default fonts. Is there a way to load these packages but only apply `mathpazo` to the serif/math fonts and `cabin` to the sans serif fonts?

EDIT: I should note that I am using LuaLaTeX to compile.
EDIT: I want the entire figure to be the normal serif fonts and only the `\textsf{}` node that I have shown to be sans serif.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[condensed]{cabin}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={width=2.0in,height=2.0in,scale only axis}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={view={0}{90},ymin=0,ymax=0.3048,xmin=-0.1524,xmax=0.1524,minor tick num=4,point meta min=0,point meta max=1.5}}

\begin{axis}[colorbar,colormap/jet,xlabel={$x$-Position, [m]},ylabel={$y$-Position, [m]},
colorbar style={at={(1.03,0.5)},y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,/tikz/.cd},
anchor=west,ylabel={Velocity, [m/s]},minor tick num=4,ylabel style={rotate=180}}]
    \node[draw=none,anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (rel axis cs:0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2.0in]{example-image-a}};           
    \draw[black,->,thick] (rel axis cs:0.98,0.98) -- ++(-135:0.30in);
    \draw[black,-,thick,densely dashed]  (0,0) -- (0,0.3048);
    \node[draw=none,anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs:0,0) {\textsf{SansSerif Text}};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[xticklabels={},yticklabels={}]   
    %Empty axis for plotting ticks on top of contour
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The line `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` is causing errors for me. Can you update the MWE so that it actually compiles exactly as is?

Comment: @JasonZentz It compiles just fine on my computer. You probably just need to update to the latest version of PGFPlots.

Comment: Can you compile with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`? There's no problem with them. Other than that, it seems to be a pgf bug and the proposed solution on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/384/) doesn't work on my system.

Comment: @Bernard I cannot use another compiler because some of the other packages I use are `lualatex` only. I have tried `xelatex` before but never seems to work for me. This MWE is missing some of the complexities that I have in the actual figure.

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples. It is ***not*** designed for this and is not suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few possible solutions:

### 1. Use pdfLaTeX

The fonts come out correctly if you compile your MWE using pdfLaTeX.

### 2. Use `fontspec` with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX will allow you to use `fontspec` to load any `.ttf` or `.otf` font in your system's font folder or your TeX distribution.*

Here, I have used `fontspec` to load Palatino Linotype (a system font) and Cabin (part of the TeX distribution) as the main and sans serif fonts, respectively. If you want to use a Palatino variant that comes with the TeX distribution, you can use TeX Gyre Pagella instead. Loading `mathpazo` before the `fontspec` declaration (with the `no-math` option) allows you to keep using that for your math font.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone} % removed class=minimal option from the MWE per cfr's comment belowl

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont{Cabin Condensed Regular}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={width=2.0in,height=2.0in,scale only axis}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={view={0}{90},ymin=0,ymax=0.3048,xmin=-0.1524,xmax=0.1524,minor tick num=4,point meta min=0,point meta max=1.5}}

\begin{axis}[colorbar,colormap/jet,xlabel={$x$-Position, [m]},ylabel={$y$-Position, [m]},
colorbar style={at={(1.03,0.5)},y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,/tikz/.cd},
anchor=west,ylabel={Velocity, [m/s]},minor tick num=4,ylabel style={rotate=180}}]
    \node[draw=none,anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (rel axis cs:0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2.0in]{example-image-a}};           
    \draw[black,->,thick] (rel axis cs:0.98,0.98) -- ++(-135:0.30in);
    \draw[black,-,thick,densely dashed]  (0,0) -- (0,0.3048);
    \node[draw=none,anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs:0,0) {\textsf{SansSerif Text}};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[xticklabels={},yticklabels={}]   
    %Empty axis for plotting ticks on top of contour
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*According to pp. 8-10 of the `fontspec` documentation (v2.5a), both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX allow you to load system fonts using either the font's name or filename. The documentation states that both engines also allow you to load any `.ttf` or `.otf` font that is part of your TeX distribution; LuaLaTeX lets you do this with the font's name or filename, but XeLaTeX requires you do to this with the font's filename. **However,** I wasn't able to replicate this difference between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX; on my machine, both were able to use just the font name to load fonts, regardless of whether they were in my system font folder or my TeX distribution. In other words, the example I provide here compiled successfully with both engines.

Comment: This is a good solution, however, I'm not the only one that will be using these figures so having to download/install a font package just to be able to get the same image isn't a very useful solution. Is there any way to do the same thing without having to install the font I want to use?

Comment: I should also note that the `no-math` option on the `fontspec` package doesn't work. Looked around and it seems to be an error in the current release (v2.5a) and can be corrected by using this instead `\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontspec}`

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the fact that it's not necessary to put the Cabin font files in your system font directory (XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are slightly different in this respect -- see pp. 8-10 of the `fontspec` documentation).

Comment: It is not possible to load the `mathpazo` text font using `fontspec` (or `unicode-math`, which builds on `fontspec`). So I have added the option of compiling with XeLaTeX or pdfLaTeX if you are really wedded to using the `mathpazo` text font as the main document font rather than some other Palatino variant like TeX Gyre Pagella, which comes with standard TeX distributions and can be loaded with `fontspec`.

Comment: Please do not use `minimal` for examples. It is ***not*** suitable. `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{<package>} \usepackage{<package>}` is pointlessly complicated. It makes no sense to use `\PassOptions...` here. You make it sound as if `fontspec` is specific to LuaLaTeX but it is not. You can equally use it with XeLaTeX and equally not use it with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Regardless of how I use `fontspec` it still gives the same error unless I do it that way, `minimal` or not. At any rate, I have removed the `class=minimal` option from the figure and it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: @cfr, I've made a few updates per your suggestions. (i) I had just left `class=minimal` because that was in the OP's MWE, but now I've taken that out.

Comment: @cfr, (ii) I only had added the `\PassOptionsToPackage` because the OP reported that `fontspec` v2.5a had a bug that wouldn't allow the normal `no-math` package option (see also [this](https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/119)). I couldn't test that myself at the time because I had an older version of `fontspec` that was being updated. Now that I have v2.5a, I can't replicate the problem with the normal package option reported by the OP, so I've reverted to my original `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`.

Comment: @cfr, (iii), I had isolated LuaLaTeX before because the OP said he was using that and also needed to be able to use TeX distro fonts rather than system fonts, which according to the `fontspec` manual is easier to do in LuaLaTeX than XeLaTeX. However, now I have done some additional testing, and my example seems to compile the same across both engines, despite what the `fontspec` documentation says. I hope my revised answer is clearer about this.

Comment: You can also do `\usepackage[condensed]{cabin}`, instead of using `\setsansfont`.

Comment: Are you using Linux, by any chance? If so, fonts installed for TeX may very well also be installed for the system. It is just a question of adding a `fontconfig` file under `/etc/` and lots of Linux distros do this as part of packaging TeX. (Or you can do it easily if you use upstream's installer.)

Comment: @cfr, no I'm on Windows 10 -- no Linux involved. I've checked to make sure that the font files in question are in my `C:\texlive` but not `C:\Windows\Fonts`.

Comment: Good to know. I have no idea how Windows handles fonts, so I have zero insight into why it works or how it works. On Linux, you just tell `fontconfig` to include the TeX Live font directories, effectively adding them to the list of system font directories. (That is, you don't install the fonts in both places - you just tell the font management software to look in both places, index both places etc.) But Windows is a mystery to me ;).

Comment: @cfr, the fonts included with the TeX distro do not function as system fonts on Windows (they aren't accessible in any other applications). As far as I know, there isn't a way to make them behave as such without finding the files and "installing" them (which essentially just copies them into `C:\Windows\Fonts`).

Comment: @JasonZentz That's a shame :(. I suspect the same is true on OS X, though I'm not sure how it works currently.

Comment: @cfr, my best guess is that XeLaTeX has been updated to match LuaLaTeX's ability to find a TeX distro font from its font name, but the `fontspec` documentation hasn't been updated to reflect that. I don't really have time to figure out if that's true or not, though.

Comment: Seems plausible.

Answer (score 2):

Use the TeX Gyre fonts they are part of any TeX distribution.

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={width=2.0in,height=2.0in,scale only axis}}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={view={0}{90},ymin=0,ymax=0.3048,xmin=-0.1524,xmax=0.1524,minor tick num=4,point meta min=0,point meta max=1.5}}

    \begin{axis}[colorbar,colormap/jet,xlabel={$x$-Position, [m]},ylabel={$y$-Position, [m]},
    colorbar style={at={(1.03,0.5)},y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,/tikz/.cd},
        anchor=west,ylabel={Velocity, [m/s]},minor tick num=4,ylabel style={rotate=180}}]
    \node[draw=none,anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (rel axis cs:0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2.0in]{example-image-a}};           
    \draw[black,->,thick] (rel axis cs:0.98,0.98) -- ++(-135:0.30in);
    \draw[black,-,thick,densely dashed]  (0,0) -- (0,0.3048);
    \node[draw=none,anchor=south west] at (rel axis cs:0,0) {\textsf{SansSerif Text}};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[xticklabels={},yticklabels={}]   
    %Empty axis for plotting ticks on top of contour
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is also a viable solution but would not work in this case. These figures are part of a larger document and, for consistency, needs to use the same font. There are slight differences between the TeX fonts and the fonts I used.

Comment: then replace `\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}` with `\setsansfont{Cabin}`

Comment: That's basically what Jason suggested in his answer.

Comment: yes, but he's using Type 1 math fonts instead of OpenType math

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples.